# sql row is not getting updated

Tags: android, sql, sql-update

I try to update row with new value, but the rows are not getting updated. I got this class here where I try to update the row:

```
class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    MyDB dba;
    private View editText;
    private DiaryAdapter adapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {           
        super(context);
        dba = new MyDB(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
        View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

        dba.open();
    }

    private List<String> fragment_monday;
    private Object position;
    private long itemId;


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Position is the number of the item clicked
        //You can use your adapter to modify the item
        long itemId = adapter.getItemId(position); //Will return the clicked item
        saveItToDB(itemId);
        }

    public EditListItemDialog(Context context, DiaryAdapter adapter, int position) {
        super(context);
        this.fragment_monday = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        dba = new MyDB(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
        // public void notifyDataSetChanged();
        dismiss();
        try {
            saveItToDB(itemId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveItToDB(long itemId) {
        dba.open();
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), itemId);
        dba.close();
        ((TextView) editText).setText("");
    }
}
```

In saveItToDB `dba.updateDiaryEntry(text, itemId);` is supposed to change the row value to the new one, where `itemId` tells it which row must be updated. It doesn't work and I am stuck with no idea how to solve the problem.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is the updateDiaryEntry code:

```
public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
    {

        ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
        newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

        return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

    }
```

I changed the EditListItemDialog class code, I updated `onItemClick`, `saveItToDB`, added `private long itemId;` and added `itemId` to `saveItToDB` in `onClick`. Can you please verify my code for any errors? Unfortunately I am still not able to update sql row.

Comment: Post your `updateDiaryEntry` code

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;
```

with

```
return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "= '" + rowId+"'", null)>0;
```

Also you will want to make sure you are not passing `null` or empty `String` to the method

Comment: Are you sure sure you are not passing `null` or empty `String` to the method and the passed `String` exists in the database?

Comment: how can I verify this?

Comment: Check the `String` `if(string!=null && !string.equals(""))` and for checking whether it exists in your database or not run a `SQL` query

Comment: can you please have a look at my updated code? I am trying to get row ID but no effect. It works if I specify the row number in updateDiaryEntry, but it needs to be the row that is clicked.